# Getting "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" even with "--insecure-skip-tls-verify" option in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a private Docker image registry running on a Linux VM (10.78.0.228:5000) and a Kubernetes master running on a different VM running Centos Linux 7.

I used the below command to create a POD:
`kubectl create --insecure-skip-tls-verify -f monitorms-rc.yml`

I get this:

> sample   monitorms-mmqhm    0/1    ImagePullBackOff   0  8m

and upon running:
`kubectl describe pod monitorms-mmqhm --namespace=sample`

> Warning Failed Failed to pull image "10.78.0.228:5000/monitorms":
>   Error response from daemon: {"message":"Get
>   https://10.78.0.228:5000/v1/_ping: x509: certificate signed by unknown
>   authority"}

Isn't Kubernetes supposed to ignore the server certificate for all operations during POD creation when the `--insecure-skip-tls-verify` is passed?

If not, how do I make it ignore the tls verification while pulling the docker image?

**PS:**

**Kubernetes version :**

Client Version: `v1.5.2`
Server Version: `v1.5.2`

I have raised this issue here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43924

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is actually a docker issue. Using `--insecure-skip-tls-verify` is a valid arg to `kubectl`, but it only deals with the connecition between `kubectl` and the kubernetes API server. The error you're seeing is actually because the docker daemon cannot login to the private registry because the cert it's using in unsigned.

Have a look at the [Docker insecure registry docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/) and this should solve your problem.